# Getting the LayerGroup a layer belongs to with OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have quite a few Tile Layers in my map, and they are all organized into different groups (sometimes they are even nested).

I see in API there's a [`getLayer()`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_Select-Select.html#getLayer) method to retrieve the layer a Vector feature belongs to, and a [`getLayerGroup()`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_PluggableMap-PluggableMap.html#getLayerGroup) to retrieve all groups associated with a Map.

However, I could not find anything on getting the layerGroup a layer is associated with.

Lets'say I have this situation:

```
var myGroup = new LayerGroup();
var myLayer = new TileLayer();
myGroup.getLayers().insertAt(0, myLayer);
```

Is there a way to get `myGroup` from `myLayer`?

Answer (score 1):

To get the parent group of a layer would need to write your own search function, something like

```
function searchGroups(group, layer) {
  var result;
  var layers = group.getLayers().getArray();
  for (var i = 0; i < layer.length; i++) {
    if (layers[i] === layer) {
      result = group;
    } else if (layers[i] instanceof LayerGroup) {
      result = searchGroup(layers[i], layer)
    }
    if (result) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

then call

```
var myGroup = searchGroups(map.getLayerGroup(), mylayer);
```

The `getLayers()` function you linked only works for a select interaction, you cannot determine from a random feature which layer it belongs to (and it could be in more than one) without a similar search of the features in each vector layer source.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question has already been answered, but alternatively, you also have the properties attribute for your layers, so you could add an array of group names to the layer itself. For example:

```
let parent_group = "parent_group";
let sub_group = "sub_group";


let group = new LayerGroup({
    name: parent_group,
    layers: [ 
    new LayerGroup({
        name: sub_group,
        layers: [ 
            new TileLayer() {
                properties: [
                    parent_group,
                    sub_group
                ] 
            }
        ]
    })
    ]
})
```

Then it's just a matter of looking up the layer name and looking up its properties array - probably a bit more cumbersome to setup initially, but it would save having to recursively search through layerGroups.